# Button are getting overlapped on deifferent devices using dp in relative layout

Tags: android

left one is the mobile phone and right one is the device on android studio.

[image]

Comment: show your xml code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use linear layout (horizontal) inside your relative layout and add buttons to it
2. Set linear layout's attribute weight_sum to number of buttons in a row (for example 5)
3. Set buttons' attribute layout_weight instead of explicitly defining size in dp (for example 1 for each button)
4. Duplicate your linear layout for all the rows
5. Profit